# How to show user's photo based on user_id of a blog post on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is my index.blade.php

```
<img class="img-circle img-bordered-sm" src="{{$user->photo_id ? $user->photo->file : 'http://placehold.it/100x100'}}" alt="user image">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in post model add this:

```
public function getWriterAvatarAttribute(){
    try {
        return User::findOrFail($this->user_id)->photo->file;
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e){
        return 'http://placehold.it/100x100';
    }
}
```

and in view:

```
<img src="{{$post->writer_avatar}}" alt="user image">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
<img src={{$user->photo ? $user->photo->file : 'http://placehold.it/100x100'}}" alt="user image">
```